# How to output the nodes' values of a BST from highest to lowest?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This is a question I thought it would be easy but I found I'm wrong in the last. I can finish the program without recursive but I want to ask whether this problem can be finished in recursive version or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive binary search tree traversal is basically (pseudo-code in case this is coursework):

```
def traverse (node):
    if (node == NULL):
        return
    traverse (node.left)
    doSomethingWith (node.payload)
    traverse (node.right)
:
traverse (root)
```

That's all there is to it really, just replace `doSomethingWith()` with whatever you want to do (such as print).

That will traverse in left to right order so, if your BST is ordered in such a way that left means lower, simply swap over the two `traverse` calls.

By way of example, consider the following tree:

```
       20
      /  \
    10    25
   /     /  \
  5    24    27
 /          /
2         28
```

as embodied in this example C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s {
    int payload;
    int left;
    int right;
} tNode;

tNode node[] = {  // Trust me, this is the tree from above :-)
    {20,  1,  4}, {10,  2, -1}, { 5,  3, -1}, { 2, -1, -1},
    {25,  5,  6}, {24, -1, -1}, {27, -1,  7}, {28, -1, -1}};

static void traverse (int idx) {
    if (idx == -1) return;
    traverse (node[idx].right);
    printf ("%d ", node[idx].payload);
    traverse (node[idx].left);
}

int main (void) {
    traverse (0);
    putchar ('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Running that program gives you the following output:

```
28 27 25 24 20 10 5 2
```

Comment: @Roger, for reverse in-order traversal, you just swap the traverse calls as I've stated. Or do you have some _other_ definition of highest and lowest? If so, you need to share that info with us.

Comment: I used this method before but I can not get the correct order

Comment: @Roger, that code will definitely produce reverse-sorted nodes. Is that the order you want?

Comment: Sorry, the method is right. I made something wrong in the program by myself in the previous programming. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Assuming the BST is sorted such that "greater than" nodes are on the right and "less than" nodes are on the left, a recursive function like this would work:

```
void recurse(Node* node)
{
    if (node == nullptr) return;
    recurse(node->right); // Explore all the "greater than" nodes first
    std::cout << node->value << std::endl; // Then print the value
    recurse(node->left); // Then explore "less than" nodes
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the method is right. I made something wrong in the program by myself in the previous programming. thx.